# Postgres change year from one year to another year

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

I have tried to use the following in PostgreSQL but it adds about 2000 years to the year. I am needing to change the year from 2096 to 2001 or 2000 doesn't really matter. When I run this it adds about 2000 years to the year 2096 and makes it 4096.

```
UPDATE module_warrants 
  SET receiveddate = receiveddate + MAKE_INTERVAL(YEARS :=2096 -96) 
where receiveddate >= '01-01-2094'
```

Expect the year to decrease by 96 years to 2000 from 2096.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `+ MAKE_INTERVAL(YEARS :=2096 -96)` is **adding** 2000 years (2096-96) to the current value.

But you want to *subtract* the number:

```
receiveddate - make_interval(years => 96)
```

or

```
receiveddate - interval '96 years'
```